# Base table or view not found -- although it should

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have a mysql table that is automatically being updated once per day. The script that does this update goes like the PHP code below. What it basically does, it makes a temporary table with the same structure, inserts all the data there first, then truncates the actual table and inserts the data from the temporary table. finally the temporary table is destroyed. This method is used because it significantly lowered the downtime of the actual table.

This was working fine for quite some time. Until recently, with the Debian upgrade (from Debian 8 to Debian 9, which also means the switch from MySQL to MariaDB). Now I often find this error message in the log files:

```
[Wed Sep 27 06:03:04.903652 2017] [:error] [pid 27393] [client 127.0.0.1:36794] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.table_temp' doesn't exist in /someFile.php:50\nStack trace:\n#0 /someFile.php(50): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /someFile.php on line 50
```

This error ultimately causes some of the data to be missing. If I understand it correctly, it says that the temporary table was destroyed before the inserts were finished, right? How can this happen though, considering that this is not really a `TEMPORARY TABLE`, I just use a real table and name it `temp`. Does MariaDB make INSERTs delayed, so that the php script can execute the DROP before the INSERTs are done?

This is the cron.d entry, so the script is really only executed once per day:

```
1   6   *   *   *    root      /usr/bin/wget -q http://www.example.com/someFile.php -O /dev/null
```

It is also worth noting that the script finishes executing within an hour or two, so the execution from previous day is long finished and does not interfere.

This is basically the code:

```
$dataArray = []; // much data

$db->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_temp`;");
$db->query("CREATE TABLE `table_temp` LIKE `table`;");

$tres = $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO `table_temp`
    (`field1`, `field2`)
    VALUES
    (:field1, :field2)
");
foreach($dataArray as $data){
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $res->execute();
    foreach($data as $item){
        $tres->bindParam('field1', $item['field1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $tres->bindParam('field2', $item['field2']);
        $tres->execute(); // line 50
    }
    $db->commit();
}

$db->query("RENAME TABLE `table` TO `table_old`, `table_temp` TO `table`");
$db->query("DROP TABLE `table_old`");
```

Comment: it is almost the error is telling you the table `table_temp` wasn't created before the prepare function... that is wierd because PHP should wait on `$db->query("CREATE TABLE `table_temp` LIKE `table`;");` has executed that's normal..

Comment: Whats line 50 in your code?

Comment: Line 50 is commented in the code. It's the execution of the insert query

Comment: You should use `sleep(10)` after `$db->query("CREATE TABLE `table_temp` LIKE `table`;");` it's wierd i know sleep should not be nessercy $db->query() should be blocking call

Comment: I doubt that this will resolve the problem, but I'll add it in for tomorrow's execution. Not really expecting anything from it though

Comment: What MySQL/MariaDB version are you running?

Comment: I'm using the latest stable Debian version. `# mysql --version` -> `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Answer (score 0):

## Drop; Create; (probably a lock)

Commands delayed by a lock are added to a "queue" in the order they are called.

Both mySql commands `DROP` and `CREATE` apply a `TABLE_LOCK` on the affected tables. This means your `CREATE` won't execute until the `DELETE` releases the `TABLE_LOCK`.

What is likely happening is that the order of commands to run, probably looks like this: (because it takes longer to prepare and queue the `CREATE` command, than the first few `INSERTS`)

1. DELETE TABLE (lock-table)
2. INSERT ...
3. INSERT ...
4. INSERT ...
5. CREATE TABLE (lock table)
6. INSERT ...

## PHP doesn't wait for a mysql command to finish...

... it just continues on it's merry way sending commands. *THAT* is the source of your issue here.

## innoDB transactions

Cannot use transactions to solve the issue.
[CREATE and DROP will commit a transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html).

## Take a closer look at your `$db` object.

Use one that will return a result based on successful execution of the query, such as [PDO::exec](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php). Then you *should* be able to wrap your `INSERT` statements in a conditional block (where PHP would have to wait for a response before it could check the condition).

```
$result = $db->exec('CREATE ...');

if (false !== $result && $result >= 0) {
    foreach($dataArray as $data){
        // INSERT
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `table_temp` already gets dropped in the end of that script execution. Only in very rare occassions should the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_temp;` at the beginning ever find anything to drop, thus being unable to lock anything. I'll still try to wrap those 2 statements in their own transactions. I'll report back tomorrow if the problem occured again!

Comment: @user2015253, yes, I noticed. the order of events still applies however, as that does not change the two causes: 1. php doesn't wait for sql command completion before sending more commands. 2. CREATE TABLE will take longer to prepare than INSERT. Result is still that several INSERTS can be prepared and executed before the CREATE starts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `CREATE` (or any other DDL) terminates a transaction.

Comment: Quick update: Having those additional transactions did not solve the problem

Comment: Well now we know.  :)  All that is left is getting a return value from command execution.

Comment: @RickJames, I took a closer look, `CREATE` and `DROP` commit a transaction unless the `TEMPORARY` keyword is used. However, temp tables are created _outside_ any transaction, so a `ROLLBACK` will leave the table in place.

Answer (score 0):

Zero chance of hiccup:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
...load the data into `new`...
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;  -- Atomic and 'instantaneous'
DROP TABLE old;
```

No transactions needed, etc.

One potential problem is that the 'load' could be getting data from some moving target.

**Another optimization**

Use a 'batch' `INSERT` -- that is a single `INSERT` statement with multiple rows.  It will be 10 times as fast as the equivalent number of 1-row `INSERTs`.  I recommend 100-1000 rows per batch.

Comment: I've never seen `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;` before. Does this instantly swap the names of those tables? That would be amazingly useful sometimes! I'll try if that helps and report back later :)

Comment: @user2015253 - I have a bunch of tips; that one shows up in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig and a couple of pages linked to from it.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful! Unfortunately the problem just occured again though, so while the RENAME reduces table downtime, it does not fix this issue :(

Comment: @user2015253 - I added another optimization

Comment: @user2015253 - "does not fix"??...  Please provide the revised code; maybe something else is going on.

Comment: I have updated the code above to reflect the changes. I have not changed the inserts to 'batch inserts', just the sql queries in the end changed to use the `RENAME` method now. This seems to save significant downtime, but still does not resolve the actual issue.